# how to pick value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have build a small function whose work to get value in alert box but i want to pick only 5 character from starting. here is my function

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function (){

    $(".hhh").click(function(){

        $(this).html()

    })
})

</script>

</head>    
<body>
    <div class="hhh">dd:ff:aa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There isn't a question here. Please be more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method:

```
$('.hhh').click(function() {
    alert($(this).html().substring(0, 5));
});
```

Obviously checking the length of the string before calling `substring` to ensure that it has at least 5 characters could be a good check to do.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `substr` ?

```
$(this).html().substr(0, 5);
```